# Is there a way prevent TortoiseSVN from "forgetting" the selected files when a commit fails?

Tags: tortoisesvn, commit

My problem is this:

Basically if I try to commit a change to SVN and the commit fails then all the files I have selected are lost or forgotten and I have to go back through and choose the ones I want to commit again.

This is hugely annoying and I've not been able to find a solution to it.

So, is there any way that I can get **TortoiseSVN to return to the state it was in just prior to when I pressed OK?** i.e. all my selected files and comment are restored.

I know I can get the comment back using the Recent Messages button so it would be really handy if I could also do something similar to get the file list state back to what I had too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For TortoiseSVN 1.6:

```
Settings-Dialog->Dialogs 2->Reopen commit and branch/tag dialog after a commit failed
```

in TSVN 1.7, that option is enabled by default, and only available as `Settings->Advanced->OutOfDateRetry`

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

If that is something that happens often to you, you could use [change lists in TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html). It works like that:

1. You check for modifications in your files by using the menu entry `TortoiseSVN > Check for modifications`.
2. In that dialog, you select the files you want to commit together, and select from the context menu `Move to change list > <new changelist>`.
3. You enter the name of the change list and accept it.
4. In you commit dialog, you see now the files grouped by change list, so if anything goes wrong, that information is kept then.
5. If you change the same files again and again, you may check the check box `Keep changelists` so that you may use the change list for your next commits.

Comment: Is there a way to backup this changelists? yesterday my TotoiseSVN "forgot" my changelist and "bamm" wrong commit happened! No Undo last commit feature also, which clutters unnecessarily the repository.